# Image Preview in admin form magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, image-upload, image-preview

I have admin form in which I have image upload option,
everything is working fine, but I am not able to figure out, how to display preview of uploaded image.

It will be great help if someone can help me with this. 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Namespace: **Book**
>
> ModuleName: **Flip**

Add addType() in admin form

```
 $fieldset->addType(
        'image',
        '\Book\Flip\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Renderer\Image'
        );
```

Now create renderer block(Image.php) at

> Book\Flip\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Renderer

Copy this code

```
<?php

namespace Book\Flip\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Renderer;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image
{
    protected function _getUrl()
    {   
        $url = 'book'.$this->getValue(); // book is image directory
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Now you can see image on admin form.

Comment: This works but with this, the label is not showing up in the backend form. Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Renderer in form php file..like as

```
$fieldset->addType(
    'image',
    '\Test\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Testing\Form\Renderer\Image'
);
```

Image.php file like as

```
<?php
namespace Test\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Testing\Form\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Image as ImageField;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory as ElementFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory as ElementCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Test\ModuleName\Helper\Data as TestImage;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Customfield extends ImageField
{

    protected $_imageModel;

    public function __construct(
        TestImage $imageModel,
        ElementFactory $factoryElement,
        ElementCollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        Escaper $escaper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_imageModel = $imageModel;
        parent::__construct(
            $factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $escaper, $urlBuilder, $data
        );
    }

    protected function _getUrl()
    {
        $url = false;
        if ($this->getValue()) {
            $url = $this->_imageModel
                    ->getBaseUrlMedia() . 'foldername/' . $this->getValue();
        }
        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but its not working, it shows nothing, any hint?

Comment: any error?? please check log.

Answer (score 0):

Follow given below URL or use given below code to solve the issue.
URL: [magento 2 : Display Uploaded image in admin form custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155035/magento-2-display-uploaded-image-in-admin-form-custom-module)

Custom code to be implemented

Step1: `Add addType() in admin form(Edit/Tab/Main.php)` // From where your form code is coming

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'image',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'image',
                'label' => __('Image'),
                'title' => __('Image'),
                'required' => false,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

Step2: In `Grid.php` paste this code

```
$this->addColumn(
       'image2wbmp(image)',
       [
           'header' => __('Image'),
            'align' => 'center',
           'index' => 'image',
           'renderer'  => '\Book\Flip\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Grid\Renderer\Image',
       ]
    );
```

Step3: Now create renderer `block(Image.php)` at `app\code\Book\Flip\Block\Adminhtml\Flip\Grid\Renderer adn paste this code`