# magento 2 : Display Uploaded image in admin form custom module

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I created one form in frontend and from form i submit customer details and also upload one image.

For display all above form data i created admin grid.For show details of grid data while click on grid row i want to show all data don't want to edit or save only show details.But i can't display uploaded image.Please help me to show image in admin form.

My form data as follows :

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/**
 * Newsletter Template Edit Form Block
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */

namespace [Vendor]\[Module_name]\Block\Adminhtml\Quotation\Edit;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic {

    /**
     * @var \Sample\Gridpart2\Helper\Option
     */
    protected $_statusOption;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_productloader;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory, StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
//        \Sample\Gridpart2\Helper\Option $optionData,
            array $data = []
    ) {

//$this->_statusOption = $optionData;
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve template object
     *
     * @return \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Template
     */
    public function getLoadProduct($id) {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

    public function getModel() {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('cart2quote_quotation');
    }

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
        );

        $model = $this->getModel();

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
                ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );


        $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory . 'cart2quote/images/' . $model->getLogoImage();
        $flag = false;
        if ($model->getLogoImage()) {
            $flag = true;
        }

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Quotation Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
        );


        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id', 'value' => $model->getId()]);
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
                'product_id', 'label', [
            'name' => 'product_id',
            'label' => __('Product Name'),
            'title' => __('Product Name'),
            'value' => $this->getLoadProduct($model->getProductId())->getName()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'quote_type', 'label', [
            'name' => 'quote_type',
            'label' => __('Quotation Type'),
            'title' => __('Quotation Type'),
            'value' => $model->getQuoteType()
                ]
        );


        $fieldset->addField(
                'company', 'label', [
            'name' => 'company',
            'label' => __('Company'),
            'title' => __('Company'),
            'value' => $model->getCompany()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'salutation', 'label', [
            'name' => 'salutation',
            'label' => __('Salutation'),
            'title' => __('Salutation'),
            'value' => $model->getSalutation()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'first_name', 'label', [
            'name' => 'first_name',
            'label' => __('First Name'),
            'title' => __('First Name'),
            'value' => $model->getFirstName()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'last_name', 'label', [
            'name' => 'last_name',
            'label' => __('Last Name'),
            'title' => __('Last Name'),
            'value' => $model->getLastName()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'street', 'label', [
            'name' => 'street',
            'label' => __('Street'),
            'title' => __('Street'),
            'value' => $model->getStreet()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'number', 'label', [
            'name' => 'number',
            'label' => __('Number'),
            'title' => __('Number'),
            'value' => $model->getNumber()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'zipcode', 'label', [
            'name' => 'zipcode',
            'label' => __('Zip Code'),
            'title' => __('Zip Code'),
            'value' => $model->getZipcode()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'city', 'label', [
            'name' => 'city',
            'label' => __('City'),
            'title' => __('City'),
            'value' => $model->getCity()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'country', 'label', [
            'name' => 'country',
            'label' => __('Country'),
            'title' => __('Country'),
            'value' => $model->getCountry()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'email', 'label', [
            'name' => 'email',
            'label' => __('Email'),
            'title' => __('Email'),
            'value' => $model->getEmail()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'phone', 'label', [
            'name' => 'phone',
            'label' => __('Phone'),
            'title' => __('Phone'),
            'value' => $model->getPhone()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'extra_info', 'label', [
            'name' => 'extra_info',
            'label' => __('Extra Information'),
            'title' => __('Extra Information'),
            'value' => $model->getExtraInfo()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'message', 'label', [
            'name' => 'message',
            'label' => __('Message'),
            'title' => __('Message'),
            'value' => $model->getMessage()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'delivery_date', 'label', [
            'name' => 'delivery_date',
            'label' => __('Delivery Date'),
            'title' => __('Delivery Date'),
            'value' => $model->getDeliveryDate()
                ]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
                'delivery_date_status', 'label', [
            'name' => 'delivery_date_status',
            'label' => __('Delivery Date Status'),
            'title' => __('Delivery Date Status'),
            'value' => $model->getDeliveryDateStatus()
                ]
        );
        if ($flag === true) {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'logo_image', 'label', [
                'name' => 'logo_image',
                'label' => __('Logo Image'),
                'title' => __('Logo Image'),
                'value' => '<img src="' . $imageUrl . '" width="50"/>',
                    ]
            );

           // $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[Vendor]\[Module Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Quotation\Renderer\LogoImage');

            //$logo_html->setRenderer($renderer);
        }



        $form->setAction($this->getUrl('*/* /save'));
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Comment: Share code what is not working , how else will ppl know what is the issue with the code ?

Comment: please check Form.php code in my que just updated

Comment: You should provide more info this is not sufficient to answer ?

Comment: but i just want to display image now it display img tag as a value not image preview so for that above code sufficient

Comment: https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule This will help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($flag === true) {
    $fieldset->addField(
    'logo_image', 'label', [
    'name' => 'logo_image',
    'label' => __('Logo Image'),
    'title' => __('Logo Image'),
    'renderer'  => '[Vendor]\[Module Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Quotation\Renderer\LogoImage',
        ]
    );

}
```

In LogoImage.php

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Quotation\Renderer;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\Object;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class LogoImage extends AbstractRenderer
{
   private $_storeManager;
   /**
    * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
    * @param array $data
    */
   public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, 
StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
   {
       $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
       $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
   }
   /**
    * Renders grid column
    *
    * @param Object $row
    * @return  string
    */
   public function render(Object $row)
   {
       $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
    );
       $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.'cart2quote/images/'.$this->_getValue($row);
       return '<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="50"/>';
   }
}
```

Comment: i have use the above way, but my image is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Image Form id `field_name`

> Form.php

```
$fieldset->addType('productimage', '\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Renderer\Image');
$fieldset->addField('field_name', 'productimage', array(           
   'label'     => __('Image')));
```

> Image.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Renderer;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Image extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{                   
       private $_storeManager;
   /**
    * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
    * @param array $data
    */
   public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, 
StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
   {
       $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
    /**
     * get category name
     * @param  DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        // here you can write your code.
        $html = '';

        if ($this->getValue()) 
        {
            $html = $this->getMediaImageHtml($this->getValue());
        } 
        return $html;
    }
    public function getMediaImageHtml($imageName)
    {
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
    );
        $Image = $this->getValue(); 
        $html = "<img src='".$mediaDirectory.$Image."' height='250px' width='250px'>";        
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ok, but works only if we have single image. What if we have multiple images coming into $this->getValue with comma seperated ? Like abc.png , xyz.png ? I have the similar case, i did explode and make $html as array but multiple images not coming up. Please help if anyone has solution for this