# Upload image using Generic Form in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, adminform

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 to create a custom form this form I created is generated using generic form not the UiComponent form ,in this form i need to be able to up How to add an image input to Magento 2 generic form?

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'title',
        'file',
        ['image' => 'title', 'label' => __('Image'), 'title' => __('Image'), 'required' => true]
    );
```

Comment: you are try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155035/magento-2-display-uploaded-image-in-admin-form-custom-module ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add this for image field

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'img_name',
        'image', 
        [
            'name' => 'img_name',
            'label' => __('Upload Image'),
            'title' => __('Upload Image'),
            'required' => true,
            'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png',
            'class' => 'required-entry required-file',
        ]
    );
```

> And your form must be have **enctype="multipart/form-data"** attribute.

```
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => [
                        'id' => 'edit_form',
                        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                        'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                        'method' => 'post'
                    ]
        ]
    );
```

> And  image can be save using below code in your controller **(code is only for save image not all form data)**

```
protected $fileSystem;
protected $uploaderFactory;
protected $adapterFactory;


public function __construct(
    ............................................................
    ............................................................

    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory
    ............................................................
    ............................................................

) {
    ............................................................
    ............................................................

    $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
    $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;

    ............................................................
    ............................................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    ....................................................
    ....................................................

    if ( (isset($_FILES['img_name']['name'])) && ($_FILES['img_name']['name'] != '')) 
      {
        try 
           {    
             $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'img_name']);
             $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
             $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
             $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
             $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
             $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
             $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('Your_FILE_PATH');
             $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
             if (!$result) 
                   {
                     throw new LocalizedException
                     (
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                     );

                   }
            $data['img_name'] = 'Your_FILE_PATH'.$result['file'];
           } 
           catch (\Exception $e) 
          {   
              $this->messageManager->addError(__("Image not Upload Pleae Try Again")); 
              $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
              return;
          }
      }
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
      exit();
      ....................................................
      ....................................................

}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Hi @Masquare thanks it's working, in the controller can we resize the image height and width using uploader class?

Comment: @jojo yes we can resize images

Comment: how to resize it?

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134360/magento-2-how-to-get-resize-image-for-custom-module