# The file was not uploaded. Magento 2 custom module

Tags: magento2, custom, image-upload, file-upload, uploader

I'm trying to upload image in my custom module but I always getting the "The file was not uploaded." error. I trace the code and all I can say is the $this->uploader->create() is not working.

Here my sample code.

```
<?php

/**
 * Grid Admin Cagegory Map Record Save Controller.
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Testing_Basic
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2016 Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
namespace Testing\Basic\Controller\Adminhtml\Contact;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Testing\Basic\Model\ContactFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Testing\Basic\Model\ContactFactory
     */
    var $contactFactory;

    protected $uploaderFactory;
    protected $adapterFactory;
    protected $fileSystem;
    protected $allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
    protected $fileId = 'your_file_id';
    protected $oldImage = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Testing\Basic\Model\ContactFactory $contactFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Testing\Basic\Model\ContactFactory $contactFactory,
        AdapterFactory $adapterFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_dir = $dir;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $img = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
        /* var_dump($img);die; */
        if (!$data) {
            $this->_redirect('contact/contact/addrow');
            return;
        }
        if(isset($_FILES['img_title']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['img_title']['tmp_name'])))
        {
            $destinationPath = $this->getDestinationPath();
            try{
                $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image'])
                    ->setAllowCreateFolders(true)
                    ->setAllowRenameFiles(true)
                    ->setAllowedExtensions($this->allowedExtensions)
                    ->addValidateCallback('custom_image_upload',$imageAdapter,'validateUploadFile');
                var_dump('asdad');die;
                $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('');
                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);
                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );
                }
                $imagePath = $result['file'];
                var_dump($imagePath);die;
                $data['img_title'] = $imagePath;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());die;
            }
        }
        try {
            $rowData = $this->contactFactory->create();
            $rowData->setData($data);
            if (isset($data['id'])) {
                $rowData->setEntityId($data['id']);
            }
            $rowData->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Row data has been successfully saved.'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }
        $this->_redirect('contact/contact/index');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Testing_Basic::save');
    }

    public function getDestinationPath()
    {
        return $this->fileSystem
            ->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
            ->getAbsolutePath('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: try this link it's helps you to save image https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307807/upload-image-using-generic-form-in-magento-2-3/307823#307823

Check  and update me

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong AdapterFactory.Try this code

```
<?php
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;

class YourController extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploader
     */
    protected $fileUploader;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        ...
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        UploaderFactory $fileUploader
    )
    {
        $this->messageManager       = $messageManager;
        ...
        $this->filesystem           = $filesystem;
        $this->fileUploader         = $fileUploader;

        $this->mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // your code

        $uploadedFile = $this->uploadFile();

        // your code
    }

    public function uploadFile()
    {
        // this folder will be created inside "pub/media" folder
        $yourFolderName = 'your-custom-folder/';

        // "my_custom_file" is the HTML input file name
        $yourInputFileName = 'my_custom_file';

        try{
            $file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles($yourInputFileName);
            $fileName = ($file && array_key_exists('name', $file)) ? $file['name'] : null;

            if ($file && $fileName) {
                $target = $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($yourFolderName);        

                /** @var $uploader \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader */
                $uploader = $this->fileUploader->create(['fileId' => $yourInputFileName]);

                // set allowed file extensions
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'pdf', 'doc', 'png', 'zip']);

                // allow folder creation
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

                // rename file name if already exists 
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

                // rename the file name into lowercase
                // but this one is not working
                // we can simply use strtolower() function to rename filename to lowercase
                // $uploader->setFilenamesCaseSensitivity(true);

                // enabling file dispersion will 
                // rename the file name into lowercase
                // and create nested folders inside the upload directory based on the file name
                // for example, if uploaded file name is IMG_123.jpg then file will be uploaded in
                // pub/media/your-upload-directory/i/m/img_123.jpg
                // $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);         

                // upload file in the specified folder
                $result = $uploader->save($target);

                //echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); exit;

                if ($result['file']) {
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('File has been successfully uploaded.')); 
                }

                return $target . $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? I check and compare your code and mine and we are using the same path and same adapter factory.

Comment: I haven't use this  $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();