# Display custom image in admin edit form magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, image

How do i display custom image only in admin edit form .. But dont want choose file button

code:

```
 $fieldset->addField(
                'file_path','image', [
                    'name' => 'file_path',
                    'label' => __('Logo Image'),
                    'title' => __('Logo Image'),
                    'renderer'  => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Quotation\Renderer\LogoImage',
                ]
            );
```

[image]

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152434/image-preview-in-admin-form-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

Just use type `'image'` and it will show you the last uploaded image in thumbnail

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'file_path',
    'image',
    [
        'name' => 'file_path',
        'label' => __('Logo Image'),
        'title' => __('Logo Image'),
        'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
    ]
);
```

You don't need to use `renderer` in it

Comment: want to display image alone need not all these button labels and all

Comment: Magento uses form elements in admin forms, you cannot show just image here, it should be and element (input, select etc). But you can show uploaded image on grid, but not on form. I don't think this is possible in magento

Comment: ya.. i can disabled  but i could not hide button and labels